# "What date is it in China?" or "What date is today in China?"

Tags: word-usage

These 2 both look correct to me:

> What date is it in China?
>   What date is today in China?

Is any of them better than another?

Comment: English speakers would likely say just _"What's the date in China?"_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What date is it in China?
>   What date is today in China?

both are correct and understandable.
Your first sentence

> What date is it in China?

would usually be understood to be asking about *today*.

More idiomatic may be

> What date is **it today** in China?
>   What is **today's date** in China?